# display image from attribute table in infotemplate

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

i have added image in attribute table. it looks like this 
[image]

now i want to display this image into infotemplate

so far i am doing like this

```js
var content = "<b>Name</b>: ${name}" +         
       "<br><b>Picture</b>: ${Pic}" +
       "<br><b>Last Name</b>: ${lname}" ;
        var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${FIELD_NAME}", content);
```

but it does not display image its empty

Comment: Is `Pic` attribute the URL of the image?

Comment: it shows like the pic i had shared

Comment: i had inserted the image in the pic field using Arc map

Comment: is there any solution of this problem or not? what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I am not quite sure what is the value of a `esriFieldTypeRaster`, that is what I am assuming you are using. If the service is public please add it to the question in order to help you. If it is not public, please add an example of the value you are receiving in that field.

Comment: in arcmap the inserted image is displaying in identity window but does not display in infotemplate

Comment: yes i have raster data type

Comment: You see, the content is HTML so is important to know if you are receiving an endpoint or the image data, or something else. I haven't use raster field, that is why I am asking you to add the value that the rest API is sending you. To know how to construct the info template. .